# JPanel background image not getting changed

Tags: java, image, swing, jpanel, paintcomponent

I am using following class for adding background image to JPanel.

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/Panelwithbackgroundimage.htm

But when the application is executing and image is changed the new updated image is not shown on screen.

```
    Image image = new ImageIcon(path + item.getItemID() + ".png").getImage();
    panel = new ImagePanel(image);
```

variable path is static path outside workspace.

Comment: try `panel.repaint()` after image change. Also, how do you change the image? are you creating a new ImagePanel?

Comment: tried with this and also by updating JPanel with new JPanel. but getting same old image.
Changing image manually in paints

Comment: Also if the image is deleted from the path the applications shows the image to JPanel background

Answer (score 1):

If you "update JPanel with new JPanel" you are not "updating", you are **creating** a new JPanel.
Example, we have a green JPanel called "panelTest":

```
panelTest = new JPanel();
panelTest.setBackground(Color.green);
add(panelTest);
```

And now we have a button that will change the JPanel background color from green to red, but in a wrong way:

```
JButton btnTest = new JButton("Test");
btnTest.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        panelTest = new JPanel(); //woops, now we have 2 panels...
        panelTest.setBackground(Color.red);
    }
});
```

Note that `panelTest` was a pointer to a green panel, and now it is pointing to a new JPanel with a red background. This new JPanel has not been added to any container, thus it will not be shown. And the old green panel will stay visible.

The best way to update the image is creating a method inside ImagePanel like:

```
public void setImage( Image image ) {
    this.img = image;
    this.repaint();
}
```

This way you don't have to create a new ImagePanel just for changing the background.

Comment: I am not only creating new JPanel but the parent frame JInternalFrame is also new.

Comment: ok @Kidaaaa why don't you share some code so we can see where the problem is?